# Importing functions from powershell module based on users rights

Tags: powershell

I work in an environment that is very restrictive and writting multiple powershell modules based on user access is a little tidias. Ive been looking through google today trying to find anything on importing functions based on users ad groups. I would like to mimic what Exchange dose but its hard to find information on it.

Dose anyone have or know resources that would handle importing functions based on user rights?

One item I have looked at is creating an xml with the function name and the groups allowed to run it but I want to make sure I look at all my options before i do anything.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Just Enough Administration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn896648.aspx)

Comment: JEA might or might not help you depending on what you want to achieve, I believe it doesn't work for local PS, it does work when remoting thou

Comment: My goal is for the local computer.